# Can we set AWS IAM account password policy for set of users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I am looking for a way to set a IAM account password policy to only set of users in the account, is this possible with IAM?

For example,
I want developers to have minimum 10 letters password,
I want testes to have minimum 12 letters password.

Creating new account for different teams is not an option.

Comment: The password policy is _per account_ unfortunately.  

This also seems like a very odd requirement.  Are your testers and developers using password managers? If not, this is a much better solution to your problem as you can then set your minimum password length to something like '32' and be confident everyone is using a secure password.

Comment: @LukePeterson Agree, I think the requirement is somewhat related to UX, just checking if it is possible with IAM. thanks for the reply.